# Adding options to Froala Editor v2 after initialize

Tags: javascript, froala

Froala v2 has removed the "option" method in v2. Is it possible to change options after the editor has been initialized? Something like this:

```
var $title = $('#title');

$edit.on('froalaEditor.save.before', function (e, editor) {
   $edit.froalaEditor('option', 'saveParams', {
      title: $title.val()
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

How to get the Froala editor instance:

```
var editor = $('.textarea-selector').data('froala.editor')
```

Then you can reconfigure your Froala:

```
var newOpts = {saveParams: {title: $title.val()}}
$.extend(editor.opts, newOpts)
```

https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

Try as shown below.

```js
var $title = $('#title');

$edit.on('froalaEditor.save.before', function (e, editor) {
    $.extend(editor.opts.saveParams, {
        title : $title.val()
    });
});
```

Comment: A note: this doesn't allow you to turn on/off a feature. I needed to set `imageUploadToS3` after initialization. In order to make this work, I first set it to an invalid value (during initialization) and then overwrote it later.